# How long could you survive while drowning in a cage?

Tags: magic

How long would someone survive, and what would he be capable of, if locked inside a metal cage and dropped into an ocean with heavy weights?

Here's the scenario. The big bad is known to dispose of naughty underlings using the aforementioned cage. To prevent easy escapes, the cage is kept in an anti-magic field that extends to just below the water's surface, and any obvious magic items will be confiscated. A small material component or focus could be hidden in a pocket, but would have to be retrieved before you drown. The mole is afraid of being found out, so he plans to escape; he knows some magic, and can prepare specific spells in readiness for the inevitable.

(Side question: What would actually kill him? Pressure? Inhalation of water?)

Important considerations:

- How long is he alive and conscious? Obviously there'll be no casting hour-long spells. He cannot breathe underwater, though he can hold his breath.
- If the escape method (eg spell) depends on speech, how possible is it to speak underwater?
- Somatic components (gestures) - how long do you have before you're pinned down by the water?
- Etcetera.

Answers based on reality are preferred over those based on RPG rules, but if specific spells etc are needed, borrow from the definition of D&D 3.5th Ed or Pathfinder.

Comment: Could you add in more info on how the magic works, do they have magic to breathe underwater or something? Or at the very least give a link on those DnD rules

Comment: Link to SRD added, and also a note that he has no underwater breathing skills.

Comment: Have you considered http://rpg.stackexchange.com/ if you're sticking to D&D rules

Comment: Just wondering, what's stopping the guy from using something like disintegration after his cage drops below the water surface?

Comment: Could do that. Is there an acceptable way to migrate a question? (This started out as less strictly defined, and then I realized that I'd need SOME form of rules about magic, or the question can't be answered. I picked 3.5th Ed because it's what I'm most familiar with, and don't have to invent all my own rules.)

Comment: @Skye: He most certainly can, assuming he can cast the spell before he dies. Hence the question. I don't know how long he would have before he dies, and I don't know how much he'd be capable of.

Comment: And, @Separatrix, I've added some more info that may help decide whether it belongs here or on rpg.

Comment: @rosuav  Yup the magic part complicates things. But the longest an average person can hold their breathe is about 40 seconds to 2 mins. The world record is 22 mins  and 22 seconds by an athlete.https://www.quora.com/On-average-how-long-can-someone-hold-their-breath-underwater

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-depth-a-human-body-can-go-to-under-water-beyond-which-the-pressure-would-be-intolerable This and http://www.medicaldaily.com/breaking-point-how-much-water-pressure-can-human-body-take-347570 should help. Regarding pressure

Comment: @rosuav If you want this question to be migrated to a different site in the Stack Exchange network, then you should "flag" it (the action link is just below the question's tags), select "for moderator attention", and explain that you want it migrated and to where. A moderator will then look into the matter (which possibly includes discussing with the target site moderators whether the question is likely to be well-received) and take appropriate action.

Comment: Hi, rosuav, welcome to Worldbuilding! In its current form, your question wouldn't be appropriate for RPG Stack Exchange because it strongly focuses on answers based on our world, not the game world. I suggest that you rewrite the question to focus only on that aspect, and then re-ask it on RPG Stack Exchange, possibly with a link to this question. I normally wouldn't recommend cross-posting, but John Dallman's answer likely wouldn't be appropriate there, and might be deleted. In this case, then, I think redoing the question there might be better.

Comment: Thanks @HDE226868 - I actually prefer it in this form, as fundamentally about reality rather than about gaming. I'll edit to downplay the D&D aspect some more and then it should be able to fit here, right?

Comment: If a spell to breathe underwater is too difficult, it has to change his anatomy and physiology, then let me suggest the diving reflex. Marine mammals like seals, dolphins and whales are adapted to stay underwater for up to half an hour. This adaptation is the diving reflex. if your caged man can cast a diving reflex spell, he will survive underwater for up half an hour. Using other gesture spells he can now escape at his leisure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person in a metal cage won't sink all that quickly, because they have lots of drag. Adding weights will increase the sinking speed, but this whole method of execution seems to be intended to cause suffering, so a sinking speed of more than about five feet per second seems unlikely.

The time available for action is as long as you can hold your breath. The sport of [Freediving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freediving) deals with that, but its records on Wikipedia aren't complete, and the people who do that have a *lot* of training. Once you can't hold your breath any more, you'll start to inhale water, and lose the ability to take any kind of constructive action. Wikipedia's article on [drowning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drowning) has lots of detail. You should have at least 30 seconds, which is plenty if you can get the magic right.

To use magic, you need a spell that has no verbal components, or has only one word. An obvious place to start is a spell that lets you breathe water. I'm not too familiar with D&D 3.5, but its Water Breathing spell has a casting time of "One standard action", and you presumably need to turn it into a "swift action", which is possible with a metamagic feat. Once you have Water Breathing up and running, you're fine, and can take other actions at leisure.

Tricks like this are the reasons for points 4 and 7 in the [Evil Overlord List](http://www.eviloverlord.com/lists/overlord.html).

Comment: Makes sense. The overlord is going to need a LOT of work to prevent this. Back to the old drawing board :)